# can't pass a ToIntBiFunction as a parameter in lambda expression in java

Tags: java, lambda

I'm currently started to learn Lambda Expressions in Java and I'm trying to figure out why this code doesn't work
I have a general class:

```
import java.util.function.ToIntBiFunction;


public class testclass {

    public testclass() {

    }
    public static ToIntBiFunction<Integer,Integer> multit2 = (Integer a,Integer b)->{
        return a*b;

    };

    public static Integer multit(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a*b;
    }
}
```

and the main in another class

```
public class ImageCovertor{

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

    int d;
    testclass test = new testclass();

    BiFunction<ToIntBiFunction,Integer, Integer> ddd = (ToIntBiFunction fn, Integer a)->{
        return fn.applyAsInt(a,a);
    };
    d= ddd.apply(testclass::multit, 5);
    System.out.println(d);

}//end of main
public static ToIntBiFunction<Integer,Integer> multit = (Integer a,Integer b)->{
    return a*b;

};


}
```

and I'm trying to pass the multit as a parameter in the ddd lambda fuction 
but this like of code gives me an error:

```
d= ddd.apply(testclass::multit, 5);
```

The type testclass does not define multit(Object, Object) that is applicable here

also tried to make the function in the main but it gives me the same error
the code works when I write

```
testclass.multit
```

instead of

```
testclass::multit
```

can someone explain to me why the second one doesn't work and how to fix this?
thank you

Comment: There is no method `multit(...)` within `testclass`. You have a static field `multit` within `ImageConvertor`.

Comment: @Turing85 it was my mistake I copied the wrong name, now I fixed it

Comment: You are using a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) in `ddd`'s type definition (`ToIntBiFunction` shoudl be `ToIntBiFunction<Integer, Integer>`). Also, to avoid unnecessary casting, method `multit` in `testclass` should return an `int` instead of an `Integer`.

Comment: @Turing85 thank you changing to 'BiFunction<ToIntBiFunction<Integer, Integer>' worked fine, I guess I should have let my function know the type of function it gets and what type of paramaters. thank you

Answer (score 1):

`testclass::multit` means a method `multit` belonging to `testclass`. What you have is a field `testclass.multit` that holds a function. A field holding a function is not the same as a method.

```
class MyClass {
    // This is a method, `MyClass::foo`
    public static Integer foo(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a*b;
    }
    // This is a field holding a function, `MyClass.bar`
    public static ToIntBiFunction<Integer, Integer> bar = (Integer a,Integer b)-> {
        return a*b;
    };
}
```

Comment: tried changing public static int multit(int a, int b) {
  return a*b;
 } to testclass and then useing testclass::multit it gives me the same error

Comment: @eyalmazuz I can't solve new problems in code I haven't seen.

Comment: @eyalmazuz of course it does. Again `testclass::multit` means that class `testclass` has a **method** `multit`. But what you have is a **field** of type `ToIntBiFunction<Integer,Integer>`.